# How to pass the remote IP to a proxied service? - Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gevent

I'm running a service in localhost at `127.0.0.1:8000`

and I'm proxying this by using:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
```

**Problem is that I need to pass the user's IP address to the service.**

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I send the real IP to django by setting a custom header:

`proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;`

Those headers are available in `request.META`

Comment: Access from Django via `request.META['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']`.

Comment: I confirm both the answer and the comment by eli_mach are correct.

Comment: Works for me, thanks. Here's how I got the values out of Pyramid (Python): `if 'X-Real-IP' in request.headers and request.headers['X-Real-IP']:
    ip_address = request.headers['X-Real-IP']`

Answer (score 3):

See http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRealIpModule