# GCP K8s native ingress preserve client IP

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

Given a K8s cluster on GCP with a service configured with:

```yaml
externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

and the pod behind the service being an Nginx container.

How can I get the client source IP?

The current issue I don't get client real IP, I get k8s cluster node kind of IP

Answer (score 1):

There a [similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880283/how-to-pass-the-remote-ip-to-a-proxied-service-nginx). Make sure that your nginx has the following configuration in your `server` block:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

If you are using an Nginx ingress controller it should be the [default behavior](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/miscellaneous/#source-ip-address).

Comment: that will certainly include a new header on the request with the IP on $remote_addr. My current issue its that $remote_addr its not the real client IP. somehow Nginx its not receiving the real client IP. Maybe something on the GCP Native Ingress its preventing from sending it

Comment: Are using the gce ingress controller? That basically uses a GCP load balancer.

Comment: correct, using gce ingress controller which creates a gcp lb

Comment: It's more about whether the GCP LB forwards the headers, if it doesn't then nothing after that will see them.

Answer (score 0):

The load balancer will include its own IP on the X-Forwarded-For header so we need to trust those IPs as well as the nodes IP so Nginx can resolve the real one using [http_real_ip_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html)

```
set_real_ip_from  x.x.x.x/32; // LB IP or CIDR
set_real_ip_from  x.x.x.x/16; // Nodes IP CIDR
real_ip_header  X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

Comment: how does nginx resolve the IP? Does it do a DNS query on the hostname?  Or the 'real ip' is included in some other header?

Comment: load balancers and reverse proxies add their ips to the X-Forwarded-For so the list keeps increasing, we need to tell Nginx which of those IPs to trust so it can skip it and remain with the real client ip

Comment: I see, so they are IPs in the header coming from the GCP LB.